# How do I mention user through discord bots - python

Tags: python, discord, bots, discord.py

I want to to make some code that will mention the name of the user that sends the message, this is what I have tried:

Im new to making discord bots, and python so any help would be perfect

```
@client.command()
async def hello(ctx, member):
    await ctx.send(f"hello, {member}")
```

Comment: So you want when someone uses the command to say his name??
or do you want when someone sends a message in the server the bot will send a message that says hello {the guy who sent the message} ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You can do this with `user.name`**

```py
@client.command()
async def hello(ctx):
    await ctx.send(f"hello, {ctx.author.name}")
```

**The above can be called by `{prefix}hello`, if you want to say "hello, {name}" even when user just send "hello" (without prefix), then use `on_message` event.**

```py
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author.bot: return
    if message.content.lower() == "hello":
        await message.channel.send(f"Hello, {message.author.name}")
    await client.process_commands(message)
```

Docs: [`on_message`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.on_message), [`user.name`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.User.name)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to mention the user who used the command. the `ctx` argument has a lot of attributes one of them is the author

```py
@client.command()
async def hello(ctx, member):
    await ctx.send(f"hello, {ctx.author.mention}")
```

If you want the user to say hello to another user, he can mention or just type the name.

```
@client.command()
async def hello(ctx, *, user: discord.Member = None):
    if user:
        await ctx.send(f"hello, {user.mention}")
    else:
        await ctx.send('You have to say who do you want to say hello to')
```

All of the above providing you are using `discord.ext.commands`

Answer (score 0):

This should work:
str(ctx.message.author)
Or:
str(ctx.author)

Comment: He said he is new to bots so I don't think that would help him at all
either give some explanation or give him full code